# How to choose between GPS and Network provide Android

Tags: android, locationlistener

I am working on an application with uses users current location.and i want to use GPS location if `GPS` is available else `NETWORK` provider application.
The problem i am facing is when my application is listening to NETWORK provide and user Switched on its GPS from notification area gps and network provider is not being switch i have tried to implements `GpsStatus.Listener`

and capture gpsstatus in

```
@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event)
{
}
```

but it seems its not being called when location listener is registered with network provider.

NOTE:i have seen `google MapActivity's` `MyLocationOverlay` that is using same concept i am trying.

please suggest any elegant way to achieve what i am trying.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5596683/455814 & this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6756112/455814